# How do I install QGIS Server and QWC2 via Gitpod?

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, server, hosting

Maybe this question is better suited to the Web Apps SE.

I want to create a self-hosted instance of QGIS Server and the QGIS Web Client 2, for times when I'm not on a computer with admin access (such as a library). Ever since C9.io shut down I've been using Gitpod for free self-hosting. However, unlike C9, Gitpod doesn't give you root access (instead everything is through Dockerfiles)

I found two Dockerfiles, one to install [QGIS](https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/qgis-server/dockerfile), and one to install the [QWC2](https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/qgis-server/dockerfile). However, I have no earthly clue how to "put it all together", especially since I'm not sure if Gitpod even supports docker-compose.

Or I could just use the Heroku CLI Dockerfile on Gitpod and host QGIS via Heroku...